# Dynamically change Angular's $interval delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

I have a tour service that returns a promise which resolves to a tour object. The tour object has some scenes, and each scene has some hotspots. In the main view's controller, I have a "private" `_init()` function that waits for the tour to resolve and then sets up some stuff.

I am using an interval that is supposed to shuffle through the scenes one by one ad infinitum, but I want a delay between the scenes to be based on the number of hotspots of the currently active scene, e.g. a scene with 2 hotspots should last for 7.5 seconds, a scene with 1 hotspot should last for 5 seconds, etc.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var i = 0, ready, scenesCount, activeScene, duration, transition = null;
_init();

// Later on down...

function _init()
{
    ready   =   false;

    AlexaTourApi.getTour( null).then( function ( res) {
        $log.log( 'AlexaTourController got tour', res);
        $scope.tour     =   res;
        scenesCount     =   $scope.tour.scenes.length;
        activeScene     =   0;

        duration        =   (getActiveScene().hotspots.length + 1) * 2500;

        ready           =   true;
        transition      =   $timeout( _doTransition(), duration);
    });
}

function _doTransition()
{
    activeScene =   (i++ % scenesCount);

    duration    =   (getActiveScene().hotspots.length + 1) * 2500;

    transition  =   $timeout( _doTransition(), duration);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I implemented some new code as per quirimmo's suggestion:

```
function _init()
{
    ready   =   false;

    AlexaTourApi.getTour( null).then( function ( res) {
        $log.log( 'AlexaTourController got scenes', res);
        $scope.tour     =   res;
        scenesCount     =   $scope.tour.scenes.length;
        activeScene     =   0;

        duration        =   (getActiveScene().hotspots.length + 1) * 2500;

        ready           =   true;
        _resetInterval();
    });
}

function _resetInterval()
{
    if ( transition !== null) {
        $interval.cancel( transition);
    }

    duration    =   (getActiveScene().hotspots.length + 1) * 2500;
    transition  =   $interval( _doTransition(), duration);
}

function _doTransition()
{
    activeScene =   (i++ % scenesCount);
}
```

Only now I'm getting an `f is not a function` exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `$timeout` which calls recursively another `$timeout` inside. And so on. This means that the timeouts will never stop, because they stop when the code executed inside will stop.

Change your code using `$interval` and before to start the new one, clear the previous one. And it should work fine.

P.s. equivalently I think you can also cancel the prev timeout before to start the new one. See `$timeout.cancel` method

```
var i = 0,
  ready, scenesCount, activeScene, duration, transition = null;
_init();

// Later on down...

function _init() {
  ready = false;

  AlexaTourApi.getTour(null).then(function(res) {
    $log.log('AlexaTourController got tour', res);
    $scope.tour = res;
    scenesCount = $scope.tour.scenes.length;
    activeScene = 0;

    duration = (getActiveScene().hotspots.length + 1) * 2500;
    ready = true;
    clearTimeoutAndStartNewOne();
  });
}
// here we clear the timeout and then we start a new one which is connected to the other function
function clearTimeoutAndStartNewOne() {
  if (transition !== null) {
    $timeout.cancel(transition);
  }
  duration = (getActiveScene().hotspots.length + 1) * 2500;
  transition = $timeout(_doTransition, duration);
}
// here we simply implement the logic of the timeout to be repeated
function _doTransition() {
  activeScene = (i++ % scenesCount);
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, I should modify my `_doTransition()` function so that it first cancels the interval/timeout before it goes about its business?

Comment: yes you need to clear your timeout before to start a new one. Maybe you can simply add this line before the new timeout will start in `_doTransition` and it may work: `$timeout.cancel(transition);`. Then after that, start the new timeout how you are doing

Comment: Sorry my bad. Unfortunately the fast change I suggested you creates the same issue because inside the timeout you still start a new timeout, so it doesn't stop. Updating the answer posting a bit of code, it's awful to write code here :)

Comment: @MorinoAndo try to see if now it fixes the issue. Updated the answer

Comment: That does get rid of the call stack size, but it doesn't actually shuffle the scenes. The `_doTransition` function is called only once, while I would like to have it loop forever, only with different delays between each iteration. My apologies, I should've been more clear.

Comment: oh ok I didn't get that. Why you don't rethink a bit your logic using a `$interval` as my first suggestion? It will work always on the background, and then use a condition to check in order to clear an interval and start a new one with the new duration you want to. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does indeed! I used your answer but I implemented `$interval` instead of `$timeout`. It seems to work up until it's supposed to switch, now it throws an `f is not a function` error...

Comment: :) yeah I told you it was more appropriate an Interval for that. Good. When do you get this error? Did you switch the code for clearing to `$interval.cancel` instead of `$timeout.cancel` ?

Comment: The exception is thrown the moment the `_doTransition()` is supposed to be called from the `$interval`, and yes, I did change `$timeout.cancel( transition);` to `$interval.cancel( transition);`

Comment: Sorry my bad, the code should not have the `()`. Try this please: `transition = $timeout(_doTransition, duration);`

Comment: My dude, you are a saint! After 4 hours it's finally done. Thank you so much!